# org-mode export to markdown - respect the level of headlines

Tags: org-mode, markdown

I noticed this strange behaviour when all the headlines are in the same level, say level 2, when the org file get exported to markdown, all the levels are bump to level 1.

Below is an example I run with Emacs -Q.

[image]

Is there a way to make org-mode respects the headline levels in exporting to markdown? in this example, they shuold be level 2 headlines, starts with two ##.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```org
#+BIND: org-md-toplevel-hlevel 2

** Heading

** Another
```

You will need to enable `#+BIND` keywords beforehand by customizing `org-export-allow-bind-keywords` to `t`.

EDIT: the `#+BIND:`  method allows you to set the variable for the file so that it applies during export *only*. But a local [file  variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html) setting would probably work just as well in this case. Add

```
# -*- org-md-toplevel-hlevel: 2 -*-
```

at the very top of the file, or

```
* COMMENT Local variables
# Local Variables:
# org-md-toplevel-hlevel: 2
# End:
```

at the very bottom of the file (and always make sure that it stays there even if you add more stuff to the file).

The reason I used `#+BIND:`  originally is that this variable is *only* useful when you are exporting: when you want to set a variable *only* during export, `#+BIND:`  is indispensable. In this case however it does not really matter: setting the variable when the file is *opened* (as is the case with local file variables), rather than when it is *exported*, will not affect anything: the variable will be set but it will just sit there quietly not bothering anyone; it will only spring into action when/if you export the file.

Comment: great! this is exactly what I need. thank you very much!

Comment: is there another way to set `org-md-toplevel-hlevel` for the current file without using `#+BIND`?

Comment: Edited the question to add that info, Search for questions tagged `[file-local-variables]` as well, although the manual (linked in the EDIT above) is the ultimate authority.