# Org Markdown exporter (ox-md) does not respect Footnotes level

Tags: org-mode, org-export, markdown

- Given that I have an Org document with footnotes
- And I have defined:

```
#+BIND: org-md-toplevel-hlevel 2
```

- And in my Emacs init script I have set:

```
(setq org-export-allow-bind-keywords t)
```

- When I export using ox-md: `C-c C-e m m`

**Expected**: Then I should see that the footnotes heading is a level 2 heading

**Actual**: The footnotes heading is always exported as a level 1 heading

Do I need to change another setting for this to work?

**The entire Org document:**

```
#+BIND: org-md-toplevel-hlevel 2

Post summary or tagline.

** level 1

   Post starts here. [fn:1]

   
*** level2

    lorem ipsum


** Footnotes

[fn:1] a footnote
```

**The resulting Markdown file:**

```markdown
## Table of Contents

1.  [level 1](#orgfadcdb8)
    1.  [level2](#org61fade8)

Post summary or tagline.


<a id="orgfadcdb8"></a>

## level 1

Post starts here. <sup><a id="fnr.1" class="footref" href="#fn.1" role="doc-backlink">1</a></sup>


<a id="org61fade8"></a>

### level2

lorem ipsum


# Footnotes

<sup><a id="fn.1" href="#fnr.1">1</a></sup> a footnote
```

You can download this sample files from my git repo:

1. [test.org](https://github.com/pgpbpadilla/pgpbpadilla.github.io/blob/master/_drafts/test.org)
2. [test.md](https://github.com/pgpbpadilla/pgpbpadilla.github.io/blob/master/_drafts/test.md)

Comment: alternative to using `+BIND` using file-local variables: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/76549/11978

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this was actually a bug. I reported it to the Org maintainers and it got fixed: [org-mode#6e72a4c7f](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/commit/?id=6e72a4c7f)